# Rails app heroku push undefined method `active_record' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I got error when trying push on heroku

```
   NoMethodError: undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f886b426850>

   /tmp/build_f717171e1d5b68477216bdaa906a9d9f/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_f717171e1d5b68477216bdaa906a9d9f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
```

my application.rb file

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"


Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|


  config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  g.orm :mongo_mapper
end
  end
end
```

im using mongomapper

rails 4.1.6

ruby 2.1.4

any suggestions how to fix it?

full errors log [here](http://pastebin.com/VSt4TukT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

`require "active_record/railtie"`

Mongo does not use ActiveRecord, so you are requiring a lib that is not available.

Comment: i did and still the same

Comment: Did you restart the app?

Answer (score 2):

You have to comment out all configuration settings that has to do with `active_record`.

If you look in, say, `config/environments/development.rb`, you'll find a line that says:

`config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load`

This setting is used in development to raise an exception if there are pending migrations, but since you're not requiring `active_record` anymore, this setting doesn't make sense.

Likewise, in `config/environments/production.rb`, there's a line:

`config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false`

Commenting out these lines and all other configuration settings that has to do with `active_record` will solve the issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by commented

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

in productioon.rb